# For loop with desired output in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a for-loop. The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
for i in np.arange(0,5,1):
    sigma(0)=10
    sigma(i+1)=sigma(i)+1
    print(sigma)
```

The desired output is

```
sigma=np.array([10,11,12,13,14])
```

Comment: `sigma = np.arange(10,15,1)`

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  How is `sigma` initialized?  What errors do you get.  You may need to read the guidelines on how to ask a SO question.

Comment: This looks like MATLAB influenced code - with the () indexing, and the expectation that arrays are created and extended automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct loop:

```
In [78]: sigma = [10]
    ...: for i in range(4):
    ...:     sigma.append(sigma[-1]+1)
    ...: sigma
Out[78]: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

But if you want to set values in an array:

```
In [79]: sigma = np.zeros(5,int)   # initialize
    ...: sigma[0] = 10
    ...: for i in range(0,4):
    ...:     sigma[i+1] = sigma[i]+1
    ...:     

In [80]: sigma
Out[80]: array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

In both of these I initialize `sigma` to something - a list or array.  I also display/print is AFTER the loop, not at each step.  And I use [] for indexing, not ().

But if you are using `numpy` there's no need to iterate

```
In [81]: np.arange(10,15)
Out[81]: array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])

In [82]: np.arange(5)+10
Out[82]: array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solutions below, although the question does not point the problem to be solved.

1. Simplier step:

```
import numpy as np
sigma = np.arange(10,15,1)
print (f"sigma = np.arange({sigma})")
```

2. In the codeblock below, the stop attribute can take any value assigned, since we are going to limit the output using the `if` statement.

```
import numpy as np 
for i in np.arange(start=0, stop=5, step=1):
    i = i + 10
    if i < 15:
        print(i)
    else:
        break #dosomething
```

3. Type 3:

```
import numpy as np
for i in np.arrage(start=10, stop=15, step=1):
    print(i)
```